# 302 Response for session management from ajax request

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, session, websphere-7

I am trying to manage a user session by making an ajax request to java code repeatedly

```js
function sendSessionKeepAliveRequest() {
  $.get('${URL}/sessionKeepAlive?nd=' + new Date().getTime());
}
```

and java code (spring framework used) handling this request:

```js
   

 @RequestMapping("/sessionKeepAlive")
    public String dummySessionKeepAlive(HttpServletResponse response,
      HttpServletRequest request) {
      PrintWriter writer = null;
      try {
        writer = response.getWriter();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
      }

      if (writer != null) {
        response.setContentType("application/json");

        // Sending an empty JSON response.
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        writer.write(gson.toJson(""));
      }
      return null;

    }
```

Now the issue is some times were are getting **302 Found** instead of **200 OK** which makes **jsessionid** change and session got time out.I have tested in on IE and FF and both of the browser have same behaviour.

Code is deployed on IBM websphere v7.0

Please help or any direction.Please feel free if any more inputs are required or I need to modify my question.

Kind Regards

Comment: What is the need to using GSON??

Comment: Its just a google library to convert java code to json and other way round.To send empty resonspon in json.

Comment: you can also pass just String instead of empty json

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered a so-called redirection: The url of the resource you've requested has changed. The new url is provided in the http header 'Location'.

You can either read out this location and issue another Request using this url or you can set up your response handling code to automatically follow the redirection.

Sample code:

```
function sendSessionKeepAliveRequest() {
    $.ajax(
          url:          '${URL}/sessionKeepAlive?nd=' + new Date().getTime()
        , statusCode:   {
                            302: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                                    var url_trg = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Location');
                                    $.get(url_trg);
                                 }
                        }
    });
```

***Update***

jquery ajax requests should handle 302 status codes automatically, so there might be some other problem. Could it possibly be a cross-domain issue ?

Comment: Thanks for response, collapsar.Yes I understand 302 is redirection but is there any way I can avoid this redirection as this is not occuring in my local environment and only in UAT. Is there specific setting on server end that is causing this?

Comment: Also this is happening sometimes in an hour and sometime in 10-15 min.So this isn't a good user experience. The above code is only to keep a session alive by repetadely requesting server.

Comment: The http status code is used to mark resources that have 'moved temporarily', so it's to be expected to happen only occasionally. Common user agents silently perform the redirection without feedback to the user and that behaviour is what i'd recommend to let your code emulate.

Answer (score -1):

If the purpose is just only to alive session then no need to use GSON you can pass empty String and add one annotation

**@ResposeBody**

This will help you to get ajax response.

Comment: Ok but I don't think this is causing the issue.Is it?

Comment: I have few issue while using GSON without any data or complex structure of data. so you can try out this.